# How to add virtual column in wpdb get_result statement

Tags: mysql, wpdb

i want to add a virtual column to wpdb get_results statement
this is my code and the column gid returns nothing .

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results ( " SELECT helo AS gid, calendar_id, day FROM table1" ) ;
```

Please help.

Comment: What would be in the column?

Comment: @JacobPeattie some user defined text or number

Comment: So where's the data coming from? Why would it be a virtual column? Can't you just loop over `$result` and add the data you want?

Comment: @JacobPeattie in every column gid the data 'helo' should be printed. when i loop $result the column gid is empty, other column have values.

Comment: This is really more of an SQL question than WordPress, but have you tried just putting `helo` in quotes? `'helo' AS gid`

Comment: @JacobPeattie yes i have tried using quote still the column is empty. but when i try same query in phpMyadmin it works, not with wodpress.

Comment: I just tested this on my own install (using quotes) and had no problem. Is the code in your question the real code you're having trouble with?

Comment: @JacobPeattie yes this is the code im having trouble with.

Comment: @JacobPeattie i have fixed by changing the 'gid' to something else. Thank you for spending your time looking at my problem.